# how to round of 3 numbers to 1?

Tags: java, android, timer

```
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
            timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }

    };
```

current result = 00.15.546 , desired result 00.15.5
millisecond is 3 digits I want 1 digit

Comment: Please try to formulate your question in more detail, like what you are trying to achieve, what is the current result and what should be the desired one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If(milliseconds %10<50)
 milliseconds = milliseconds/100;
else
 milliseconds = milliseconds/100 + 1;
```

scratch that it will give you a decimal number because timer is not an int my bad.  Try something like:
    Math.round(milliseconds*100)/100;
\

Comment: worked man thanks I did on more think change this String.format("%03d", milliseconds)); to String.format(String.valueOf(milliseconds)));